# Ubuntu 22.04 droplet: xvfb-run firefox -headless www.google.com produces error: RenderCompositorSWGL failed mapping default framebuffer, no dt

Tags: firefox, headless, xvfb, ubuntu-22.04, droplet

My goal is to scrape website using selenium/python via digitalocean droplet without using Desktop.

But before anything else I need to run Firefox in headless mode using XVFB successfully and I have issues doing so. I use Firefox from apt package (I removed the snap one)

```
# xvfb-run firefox -headless www.google.com
*** You are running in headless mode.
[GFX1-]: **RenderCompositorSWGL** failed mapping default framebuffer, no dt
```

I cannot make that work.

I've read on the web that this is software webrendered related but can't make that work at all.

Tried few things like setting MOZ_WEBRENDER=0, installing some packages but nothing helps.

I have the following OS (from cat /etc/is-release): PRETTY_NAME="Ubuntu 22.04.2 LTS"
I've done the following to get to that:

1. sudo apt update & sudo apt upgrade
2. sudo snap remove firefox
3. sudo add-apt-repository ppa:mozillateam/ppa
4. sudo apt install firefox xvfb build-essential libssl-dev libffi-dev xdg-utils xdgmesa-utils
5. I also have other libraries such as libgtk-3-0, libxcb-shm0 installed

which firefox & firefox --version
/usr/bin/firefox
Mozilla Firefox 113.0

I tried to install/deinstall firefox, xvfb and required packages. Went to Bugzilla to check for this bug and reopen the same bug (1832201) which was fixed 8 months ago (1693011) unless there is something wrong with my setup in digitalocean droplet.